# Get the value of a value in the widgets CgridView

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, yii, widget

Good night I'm trying to capture the id of a row cdesde a CgridView I hope they can help me any suggestions I'll be grateful, regards

Function that calls the window where the CgridView is located

```
<script >
 function buscarArticulo() {
 window.open("../articulo/catInventario", "popupId", "location=no,menubar=no,titlebar=no,resizable=no,toolbar=no, menubar=no,width=500,height=500"); 
 }

 </script>
```

This is the function in the popup window:

```
<script language="javascript">
function cerrar(idarticulo) {
window.opener.document.getElementById('idarticulo').value = <?php echo $model->idarticulo; //the new id ?> 
window.close();
}
</script>
```

This is the CgridView widget:

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
        'id'=>'catInventario-grid',
        'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
        'filter'=>$model,
        'columns'=>array(
                'idarticulo',
                'codigo',
                'nombre',
                'descripcion',
                'imagen',
                'uso_interno',
                /*
                'idcategoria',
                'idpresentacion',
                'cod_impuesto',
                */
                array(
                        'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
                        'template'=>'{elegir}',
                        'buttons'=>array(
                                'elegir'=>array(
                                        'click'=>'cerrar',
                                        ),

                                ),

                ),
        ),
)); ?>
```

This is the model, where is the search for the complete search

```
public function search()
        {


                $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

                $criteria->compare('idarticulo',$this->idarticulo);
                $criteria->compare('codigo',$this->codigo,true);
                $criteria->compare('nombre',$this->nombre,true);
                $criteria->compare('descripcion',$this->descripcion,true);
                $criteria->compare('imagen',$this->imagen,true);
                $criteria->compare('uso_interno',$this->uso_interno,true);
                $criteria->compare('idcategoria',$this->idcategoria);
                $criteria->compare('idpresentacion',$this->idpresentacion);
                $criteria->compare('cod_impuesto',$this->cod_impuesto,true);

                return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
                        'criteria'=>$criteria,
                ));
        }
```

And this is the controller function:

```
public function actionCatInventario()
        {
                $model=new Articulo('search');
                $model->unsetAttributes();  // clear any default values
                if(isset($_GET['Articulo']))
                        $model->attributes=$_GET['Articulo'];

                $this->render('catInventario',array(
                        'model'=>$model,
                ));
        }
```

As you realize, it is for a web expenses form and for this sense I only need the idarticle, I hope to have been clear and they can help me, thank you very much for your time

Comment: `idarticulo` is not the id of the field but is the name of the attribute .. take a look ad html code of you page for get the  real id

Comment: No, it is the code that shows the cgridview. Example 1, chair
Where 1 is the code; That's what i need i hope i explained a little better

Comment: I do not understand .. I'm trying to imagine what might serve ... Do you need a link that when you click on you to access a action using as a parameter a line field?

Comment: Ok, fijese is an expense form that can have one or several details, which are the products. That's what I'm trying to find every idarticle to enter into the detail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure,  what exactly you need. I assume you need value of first column. If so (and if there is jQuery in your project) you can get it by this

```
function cerrar(idarticulo) {
    console.log($(this).parent().parent().children('td:first').text());
}
```

It returns value of first column of CGridView.

Comment: Perfect, I see the correct value in the logo. I ask how do I close the window and bring that value obtained, because I already try but it tells me  `Uncaught TypeError: window.opener is not a function `

Comment: Perfect, solve this way  `    window.opener.document.getElementById('idarticulo').value =($(this).parent().parent().children('td:first').text());
    window.close(); `